# Simple Ruby Test Not Working

Tags: ruby

I am going through Learn Ruby the Hard Way and its been great up until now.I can't for the life of me figure out why my test is not working. I have spent a few hours trying to figure it out and I am sure it is something simple.

To me it looks like it is not finding the scan method but I can seem to figure out why. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code

test_lexicon.rb file

```
require_relative '../lib/ex48/lexicon.rb'
require "test/unit"

class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_directions
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("north"), 'north')
  end

end
```

lexicon.rb file

```
class Lexicon

  def scan(text)
    return text
  end

end
```

Here is the error from the terminal:

Running tests:

[1/1] TestNAME#test_directions = 0.00 s
  1) Error:
test_directions(TestNAME):
NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for Lexicon:Class
    /Users/guest1/Dropbox/ruby_projects/play/ex48/tests/test_lexicon.rb:7:in`test_directions'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1301:in `run'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit/testcase.rb:17:in`run'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:919:in `block in _run_suite'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in`map'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:912:in `_run_suite'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:657:in`block in _run_suites'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in `each'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:655:in`_run_suites'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:867:in `_run_anything'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1060:in`run_tests'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1047:in `block in _run'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in`each'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1046:in `_run'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/minitest/unit.rb:1035:in`run'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:21:in `run'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:774:in`run'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:366:in `block (2 levels) in autorun'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:27:in`run_once'
    /Users/guest1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/test/unit.rb:365:in `block in autorun'

Finished tests in 0.004470s, 223.7136 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
rake aborted!

Answer (score 3):

You've defined an instance method in your class:

```
def scan(text)
  return text
end
```

but are trying to call a class method in your test:

```
Lexicon.scan("north")
```

To make it a class method do:

```
def self.scan(text)
  return text
end
```

Edit: this answer does not address whether you should use a class, instance, or module method.

Comment: Im really new to this and thanks for being patient with me. How do I make it a class method instead of an instance method?